# How to vectorize indexing operation in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor A of shape (2, 4, 2), and a tensor B of shape (4, 4), all the values are int. Entries in A are from 0 to 3.

I want to create a tensor C of shape(2, 4, 2).

The for loop code is like:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(4):
            C[i][k][j] = B[k][A[i][k][j]]
```

How can I create such tensor C in tensorflow?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe explain what you are trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Can you include the entry values of `A` and `B`? Otherwise there might be issues in general with your code, for example if the entry values of `A` are between say 100 and 1000 (e.g. `A[1][1][1]=1000`) then `B[k][A[i][j][k]]` will throw an error...

Comment: What I am trying to do is a little complex to explain. Maybe later I would find a way to explain it clearly. And entries in A are all integers from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Input values
A = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None])
B = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
# Make indices for first dimension of B
idx = tf.range(tf.shape(B)[0], dtype=A.dtype)[tf.newaxis, :,  tf.newaxis]
# Tile first dimension indices to match the size of A
idx = tf.tile(idx, (tf.shape(A)[0], 1, tf.shape(A)[2]))
# Stack first dimension indices with A to complete index tensor
idx = tf.stack([idx, A], axis=-1)
# Make result gathering from B
C = tf.gather_nd(B, idx)
```

Here is an example, testing that the result matches your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Non-TensorFlow implementation for result comparison
A_value = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(2, 4, 2))
B_value = np.random.randint(100, size=(4, 4))
C_value = np.empty(A_value.shape, dtype=B_value.dtype)
for i in range(A_value.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A_value.shape[2]):
        for k in range(A_value.shape[1]):
            C_value[i][k][j] = B_value[k][A_value[i][k][j]]

# TensorFlow implementation
A = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None])
B = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
idx = tf.range(tf.shape(B)[0], dtype=A.dtype)[tf.newaxis, :,  tf.newaxis]
idx = tf.tile(idx, (tf.shape(A)[0], 1, tf.shape(A)[2]))
idx = tf.stack([idx, A], axis=-1)
C = tf.gather_nd(B, idx)

# Check result
with tf.Session() as sess:
    C_value_tf = sess.run(C, feed_dict={A: A_value, B: B_value})
    print(np.all(np.equal(C_value_tf, C_value)))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Well organized answer. It really helps. Thank you!